# Eclipse and Phonegap on windows for ios development?

Tags: ios, eclipse, cordova

Can I use eclipse and phone gap to develop ios based apps on windows? if yes, the is there any tutorial or video link of how to go about it? One last thing is can we call in api's also for eg. touch id api while developing this app?

Answer (score 0):

Q1: Sorry no, you need to use the XCode toolchain to develop iOS apps, and you can't install that on Windows (OS X only).

Q2: *Some* of the device APIs will work if you run your app in an emulator and the emulator supports those specific APIs (orientation, for example), but for the most part you'll need to run the app on an actual device to use the device APIs.